# Do i need shared preferences in this case?

Tags: android, authentication

I am making an android application in which a user creates his profile with some attributes that will be used later on; The first time the application is used it needs to provide the "registration" activity, but later on, I want the user to directly access the application without having to log in or see the registration page. Do I have to use shared prefrences in this case? and how would I hide that first page later after the creation of the profile for further use?

Answer (score 1):

Is there some internet component to this program? After registration, store the users' information in a private SharedPreference. You will know if a user has registered when you try to retrieve the information from the SharedPreference.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getDefaultSharedPreferences();
String login = pref.getString("login", ""); // "" is default value
if(login.equals("")){
    //startActivityForResults
    //get results, store them in sharedpreferences, then COMMIT!
    //if results are invalid(user has hit back button)
    //close to home screen
else{ //user has registered
    //do what you need to show login activity/layout.
}
```

Edit: It is also good practice to store key values in a strings.xml, or somewhere statically so you do not have magic strings.

Comment: How can I link the shared preferences fields to my Sqlite database?

Comment: What do you mean? A SharedPreferences would be used to store local information pertaining to the client. If the user logs in, you can store all the data associated with the user in their sharedpreferences.

Comment: I needed to mention that the user creates a set of attributes along with the username, he can access the system with the username, but i need those attributes (age, height, weight, gender..) to be stored with him in shared preferences to be always used.
Should I define two classes: theActivity that deals with creating the profile and PreferencesConnector that defines how to read and write and then use the following:
if (name.getText().toString() != null)
PreferenceConnector.writeString(ProfileActivity.this,      PreferenceConnector.NAME, name.getText()        .toString());

Comment: Creating the PreferencesConnector class will provide convenience. Just a bunch of get and set functions.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to use shared prefrences in this case?

No but they make your life easier here. Other options to store that data are more complicated.

> And how would I hide that first page later after the creation of the profile for further use?

Apps usually have another startpage from which they either start the login or directly the main part. You can also `startActivity` directly in `onCreate` of your start screen if you detect that you have the required data (so you don't really see that activity)

Comment: Well I am using a DB to store that user, is there any way to work with the two? i mean retrieve the data from the Database and then connecting it to the shared preferences

Comment: you can store everything in your database if you already have one. But you can combine them - shared preferences are just variables stored on disk